# ESP8266: What means stub loader in esptool?

Tags: debugging, serial-port

Can I update the firmware(`ESP8266 ROM loader`) for ESP8266 's bootloader?

Or From https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/Serial-Protocol,
What means `stub loader`?

`ESP8266 ROM loader` means `stub loader` ?

---

**EDIT:**
Also, my main problem is describe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found a [detailled description](http://stefanfrings.de/esp8266/) only in German. I guess, you could translate it pretty well with [this tool](https://www.deepl.com/translator).
I did so for the essential part (slightly improved by me):

Firmware Upload

The ESP chip contains a fixed bootloader (this is the stub loader), which allows a firmware upgrade via the serial port. When resetting, the chip expects the following control signals:

Firmware upload:
GPIO0 = Low
GPIO1 (TxD) = High by resistor or open
GPIO2 = High by resistor or open
GPIO15 = Low

Normal start:
GPIO0 = High or open
GPIO1 (TxD) = High by resistor or open
GPIO2 = High by resistor or open
GPIO15 = Low

Thus, **you can upgrade the firmware**!

Comment: Thanks your kindly help

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot: I have neither Android available, nor the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply