# Android UsbSerial library problem in ch340

Tags: android, serial-port

I am trying to convert the open-source python project [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) to the Android(java) project.
In android, for serial communication, I am using [USB Serial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library.
I need only [esp8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) feature from `esptoo.py`, so I only converted the esp8266 function.

From [UsbSerial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library, I am using [synchronous api](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/wiki/5.-Synchronous-api), because the [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) use synchronous command for Serial [read](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read)/[write](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write).
The current project is working well with esp8266/FTDI, esp8266/cp2102 same as `esptool.py`.
My problem is not working with `esp8266/ch340`.
Of course, the esptool.py is working well with `esp8266/ch340`.
But, my android project is not working with it.
In android, the main command which used in esptool.py is `setDTR`, `setRTS`, `serial Read` and `serial Write`.
Each command working well although in `esp8266/ch340` in normal mode(not bootloader mode).

Also, I confirmed the esp8266 can be bootloader mode correctly via a combination of setDTR, setRTS.
More correctly confirm bootloader mode, I can use `Flash button` and `RST button` of esp8266.
[image]
With esp8266/ch340, I cannot pass the first step with an android project.
The first step is the sync operation.

From android, call write command with https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/Serial-Protocol#initial-synchronisation, then the esp8266 is a response as bytes.
The main problem is cannot read response command from esp8266.
From UsbSerial, there are `syncRead`, `syncWrite` commands, also there is an asynchronous command for serial operation.
The `esptool.py` is made with synchronous API, So, I am using synchronous API in android project.
Also, the current project is perfect with esp8266/FTDI, esp8266/cp2102.
So, I think, the main algorithm is successfully converted from esptool.py

But, esp8266/ch340, the current project is not working.
From debug, I confirmed that I cannot read any bytes from esp8266/ch340 in bootloader mode.
For debug, I created new project using [asynchronous api](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/wiki/4.-Asynchronous-api).

With using the button of esp8266, make `esp8266/ch340` bootloader mode, I am writing the sync command to esp8266.
[image: flash button, rst button]

From https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/Serial-Protocol, the esp8266 is sending response command, but cannot read the response in `esp8266/ch340`.

*But, I found strange things.*
After bootloader mode, write sync command and disconnect the USB from android, then, I can see the correct response command in `Disconnecting moment`.
If I write sync command 3 times, then the 3 response command arrives at disconnecting moment.
**How I can solve this problem?**

How I can debug esp8266 in bootloader mode?

From debugging, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781807) is main problem in `esp8266/ch340`([bootloader mode](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/ESP32-Boot-Mode-Selection)).

Comment: Try debug with wireshark & usbpcap, you could see the actual usb comms

Comment: Can you send me more details?

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) allows you to look at frames. Used with usbpcap [UsbPCAP](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/) you can see all usb frames. More details [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB)